# awk convert number to date format to select line bigger than specific mmyy

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

**INPUT**:

```
test,1120,1
test,1219,2
```

**Expected Output**

```
test,1120,1
```

**Goal**: trying to print line where `$2` which is `mmyy` format is bigger than `1020` as example.

I've tried with the following:

`awk -F, '{ if ( $2 > 1020 ) { print $0 }}' file` that's will not give the expected output because it's still number **etc.. 1219 is bigger than 1020**.

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 2nd field always contains 4 digits, how about:

```
awk -F, 'substr($2, 3, 2) substr($2, 1, 2) > 2010' input
```

Please note that I have interpreted the word `bigger` as `later`, meaning `0921` is `bigger` than `1020`. If my assumption is incorrect, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned that now if dates require lesser than provided input in that case one could try following.

```
awk -v val="1020" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  user_year=substr(val,3)
  user_month=substr(val,1,2)
}
{
  year=substr($2,3)
  month=substr($2,1,2)
  if(year==user_year){
   if(month<user_month){
     print
   }
  }
  else if(year<user_year){
     print
  }
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. I have create a variable named `val` here which will have value which user needs to compare to all the lines of Input_file. In this case it is set to `1020`

```
awk -v val="1020" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  user_year=substr(val,3)
  user_month=substr(val,1,2)
}
{
  year=substr($2,3)
  month=substr($2,1,2)
  if(year==user_year){
    if(month>user_month){
      print
    }
  }
  if(year>user_year){
      print
  }
}
' Input_file
```